# Replacing existing 9" dome fixtures with new 13" ones

Tags: electrical

I purchased three 13" LED dome fixtures for my kitchen over the sink and the two bathrooms.  I removed the original fixture and the existing brackets screws are only 4" apart.  The new fixtures do not include brackets.  The old bracket would have to accommodate screws 6" apart which it does not.  Can anyone explain to me, how do I mount these?  Do they make longer brackets or do I have to change the boxes out?  Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Please post some photos of the old and new light fixtures and the brackets in question.

Answer (score 2):

Holes 6" apart for a lamp fixture are not very common. You need larger or adjustable **[crossbar](http://www.bplampsupply.com/product/2300_e-z-adjustable-crossbar)** (also called a fixture bracket)

[image: adjustable bracket]

You can attach this type of bracket to standard boxes with holes at 4" or 3 1/2".

Depending on whether the crossbar you find is threaded at 6", you may need to install machine screws in the crossbar slots, locked into place with nuts, that then stick down through your fixture mounting holes.

```
The links and images are for illustration only and are not an endorsement
```